# Проблемы с unity ads

Tags: unity3d, ads

Я пишу игру на юнити 2019 версии. Возникла необходимость подключить монетзацию, но при попытке инициализировать рекламу, выходит вот это сообщение
Please consider upgrading to the Packman Distribution of the Unity Ads SDK.  The Asset Store distribution will not longer be supported after Unity 2018.3
Есть какие-то мысли на этот счет? Я искал много информации на англоязычном сегменте, но не нашел ничего такого, что могло бы помочь...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С 2019+ версии Unity начали плавный переход от *Asset Store*'а к ***Pack**age **Man**ager*'у. Все, что вам нужно сделать - установить Unity Ads через Package Manager:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]